# React - Objects are not valid as a React child when creating array of JSX components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am converting a project from the old `React.createComponent` to new the ES6 class definition. I have the following component:

```
class AnswerFrame extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        var props = this.props;
        var selectedNumbers = props.selectedNumbers.map(function (i) {
            return (
                <span onClick={props.unselectNumber.bind(null, i)}>
                    {i}
                </span>
            )
        });

        return (
            <div id="answer-frame">
                <div className="well">
                    {selectedNumbers}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

The idea is to define an array, `selectedNumbers` which is an array of spans that each have an onclick event. These are then rendered.

This code worked fine before converting to ES6 but now is giving me the following error:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child 
(found: object with keys {dispatchConfig, _targetInst, nativeEvent, type, target, currentTarget, eventPhase, bubbles, cancelable, timeStamp, defaultPrevented, isTrusted, view, detail, screenX, screenY, clientX, clientY, ctrlKey, shiftKey, altKey, metaKey, getModifierState, button, buttons, relatedTarget, pageX, pageY, isDefaultPrevented, isPropagationStopped, _dispatchListeners, _dispatchInstances}).
If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `AnswerFrame`.
```

Why is this not working anymore?

Comment: what that array contains, its an `array` of `number/string` or `array of objects` ? can you show the result of `console.log(this.props.selectedNumbers)` ?

Comment: I think this message is about the contents of  `this.props.selectedNumbers`. Are you sure there are numbers?

Comment: Maybe the lack of the `key` property in your span elements causes this problem?

Comment: yes selectedNumbers is not an array of numbers which it should be

Comment: If it helps it looks like selectedNumbers is an array of event objects, so I suspect the problem is where you're populating selectedNumbers. You're probably passing an event to something that is expecting event.target.value?

Comment: Alex, can you include the code that calls the `<AnswerFrame />` and provides its props?

Comment: "is not an array of numbers which it should be" then the problem is in root component where you are rendering `AnswerFrame` passing incorrect property. To avoid such an issue you need to specify property type of `selectedNumber: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.number).isRequired` https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Comment: Yeah I forgot a null in a bind so the selectedNumbers was an array of event objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep turns out the problem was in `props.selectedNumbers`. Trying to figure out the change in the way `this` is bound when you use `ES6`, I removed a null from a bind somewhere else in the code.

This:

```
numbers.push(
    <div className={className} onClick={selectNumber.bind(i)}>
        {i}
    </div>
);
```

should've been

```
numbers.push(
    <div className={className} onClick={selectNumber.bind(null,i)}>
        {i}
    </div>
);
```

So `props.selectedNumbers` was the object causing the problem.

Comment: I dont know what that does tbh but this solved a random big error of mine, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Binding in react props is bad practice (https://daveceddia.com/avoid-bind-when-passing-props/), consider making selectNumber a higher order function:

```
const selectNumber = (i) => () => {
    // your original function code here
    doWhateverWith(i);
}
```

And setting onClick to:

```
<div className={className} onClick={selectNumber(i)}>
```

Comment: Using that approach, how would you go about re-using that function in different classes? Currently I'm defining `selectNumber` in a parent component and passing it to its children.

Comment: @AlexLogan To selectNumber in one action, you can either call it like this in your child functions: `selectNumber(i)()` or pass it down as `(i) => selectNumber(i)()`

Comment: What might be more coherent though is defining selectNumber as you originally did, but in this case, defining a `clickHandler` function as `(i) => () => selectNumber(i)` and doing `onClick={ clickHandler(i) }`

Comment: Whoops, didn't notice that, my bad. Most of my comment is till correct though ;) (will remove)

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is just another way of doing the same thing but...

```
members.push(
    <div className={className} onClick={() => {selectedNumber(i);}}>
       {i}
    </div>
);
```